# Trouble with Cross-Origin Headers: Stripe and ffmpeg Integration in Next.js

Tags: next.js, ffmpeg, stripe-payments, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy

I'm using this excellent template from vercel as a base for my project :

```
https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/subscription-starter
```

I've used it for many projects and the Stripe integration works flawlessly. However for a new project I needed to incorporate ffmpeg which relies on **SharedArrayBuffer**:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer
```

So I need to set the  appropriate HTTP response header which i've set in my next.config.js file as below:

```
      {
        source: '/(.*)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy',
            value: 'credentialless'
            // value: 'require-corp'
          },
          {
            key: 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy',
            value: 'same-origin-allow-popups'
          }
        ]
      }
```

Now the issue is that settings these breaks Stripe. It blocks the request:

```
https://js.stripe.com/v3/m-outer-3437aaddcdf6922d623e172c2d6f9278.html
```

Which appearently loads more resources that are needed for the checkout session to function. The customer portal works   but checkout doesn't. I've literally tired every possible permutation of  headers with different values but in all cases either Stripe works but ffmepg doesn't (cause SharedArrayBuffer doesn't work) or vice versa. It's been a week and I've tired everything and can't find anything online that works. Not even ChatGPT can help which ironcelly asks me to contact Stripe customer support. I would highly appreciate if anyone could even point me in the right direction. I Thank you in advance good Sir/Maam.

Note that Checkout works fine with just:

```
key: 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy',
value: 'same-origin'
```

Just  `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy`  breaks it

Answer (score 2):

I reached out to a Stripe developer through their Discord Server, and here's what they had to say:

> It looks like we don't currently support Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy
> today, but it is on our radar I don't have an ETA to share
> unfortunately.
>
> You can write in via our support form requesting this feature
> https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true

Currently, the only feasible solution appears to be relocating your ffmpeg code (which relies on SharedArrayBuffer) to a different server.

**EDIT:**
I deployed my ffmpeg code a separate server and connected it to my main site which has Stripe and now the program is working perfectly.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue. Could you clarify what your solution entails, do you run the ffmpeg code on the server or do you redirect to a new page when you need the cross-origin-isolation and redirect back for the stripe integration?

Comment: Hi, I needed to create a Chrome plugin capable of transcribing A/V. I used FFmpeg to transcode V to A and compression. For this, I started a new NextJS project and deployed it on Vercel, alongside another deployment for the main website that includes Stripe. When users upload A/V through the plugin, it triggers a popup window directing them to the ffmpeg website, which is entirely isolated from the main website with Stripe. Additionally, I secured the FFmpeg endpoint to ensure only users with the correct auth tokens could upload A/V. I hope this clarifies things.